# Convert ArrayList<Model> to MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Model>> in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, mutablelivedata

What i am trying to do is to convert the `ArrayList<Model>` to `MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Model>>` to be send as a return value. Though i am getting the `ArrayList<Model>` result correctly,i failed miserably in posting the value to `MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Model>>`.

This is what i am trying to do...

```
suspend fun getSeasonBodyWeight(): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<MSBodyWeight>> {
    val x = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<MSBodyWeight>>()
    val y:ArrayList<MSBodyWeight> = getBWeightCoroutine()
    x.postValue(y)
    Log.i(TAG, "Check ${y.size}")
    Log.i(TAG, "Check ${x.value}")
    return x
}
```

This is what i getting in Logcat

```
I/FirebaseConnect: Check 2
I/FirebaseConnect: Check null
```

So what am i doing wrong. Also how to convert `ArrayList<Model>` to `MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Model>>`

I am trying to learn Kotlin.. Please bear with me if its a NOOB question.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `postValue` and if you check the source code you will find in the method description:

`Posts a task to a main thread to set the given value.`

Means that the value will not be immediately set, it starts a task to change it. If you mean to change the value immediately you should use:

```
x.value = y
```

The difference between the two is that you cannot call `setValue` from a background thread, that meaning, if you are in a background thread you should call `postValue`. If you are in the main thread `setValue` may be used

Answer (score 0):

```
suspend fun getSeasonBodyWeight(): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<MSBodyWeight>> {
    val x = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<MSBodyWeight>>()
    x.value = arrayListOf();
    val y:ArrayList<MSBodyWeight> = getBWeightCoroutine()
    x.postValue(y)
    Log.i(TAG, "Check ${y.size}")
    Log.i(TAG, "Check ${x.value}")
    return x
}
```